# Why am I not getting a stack trace vs code in the edit area?

Tags: xcode, debugging, swiftui

I noticed that I'm getting what looks like a stack trace vs source code in the main edit area; which forces me to use the 'list' command in the console area.

Why?

[image]

Here's the source:

[image]

Comment: What version of xcode are you using? And also are you running the app in the preview or the simulator?

Comment: Xcode 12 GM; running simulator.

Comment: Can you see where the debug area would be? Bottom right corner, if you can, try self.doSomething()

Comment: I got the console; and I rewrote my question.

Comment: Check the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78165185/how-to-change-stacktrace-to-code-edit-in-xcode-source-editor-area/78178135#78178135

Answer (score 0):

The situation you are in looks like you did a Step instruction while holding the Control key, which will wind you up in assembly language. My guess is that if you click the 0 line in the debug navigator again, you'll see your source code.