# How to change StackTrace to Code Edit in xcode source editor area

Tags: xcode, debugging, breakpoints

Xcode runtime enabling breakpoints goes to stack trace in main source code editing area where we could not see the source code to debug.

I'm using Xcode 15 and SwiftUI.
How can we change it to source code in main editing area.

Below is the source editor screenshot for reference:
[image: Xcode debug breakpoint view]

Comment: Are you sure a corresponding Swift file for this location even exists? Please show a [mcve].

Comment: yes the file exist in location

Comment: That is not a [mcve]. Describe the steps needed to reproduce this problems, starting from "start a new Xcode project", and make it clear which line in which file you expect the breakpoint to trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution. Uncheck `Xcode-> Debug-> Debug Workflow -> Always shows Disassembly` Which removes the stack trace while running breakpoints and shows code edit on source editor area

Check the below screenshot for the navigation in settings

[image]